# php5-fpm connection timeout/connection refused

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

We have a webpage with ~20000 pageviews/day. This page usually uses ~15-20 php5-fpm children, but sometimes it reaches the maximum number of children and the site will be unavailable about ~15 mins. (150) It doesn't happen necessarily in peak time. And php5-fpm/nginx restart doesn't help, when I restart the php5-fpm, It instantly reaches the max number of children.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my config files:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxIEpo_vWLGZeFVZUXBMRTA3QXc&usp=sharing

I don't know how can I find what causes it. What should I do for fix this issue?

Comment: Still we have this problem. :(